# NavigationMixin to Community TestPage not working

Tags: lightning-web-components, community-builder, experience-cloud, navigationmixin.navigate

### TL;DR

Is there way to debug the `NavigationMixin`? `My Button` fires the navigation method and nothing happens.

Hello, I'm not sure what's going wrong here. My understanding is that this setup should be sufficient. When I console log a message, I can determine that my button is activating, but the NavigationMixin is not firing the new page. The page is just a a page with a default Rich Content element that says "Thank You" there is no additional logic on that page.

### HTML

```
<template>
    <lightning-button label="My Button" onclick={navigateToInternalPage}></lightning-button>
 </template>
```

### JAVASCRIPT

```
   import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
    import getUserData from '@salesforce/apex/CommunitiesData.getUserData'; 
    import { getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
    import ID from '@salesforce/user/Id';
    import FIRST_NAME from '@salesforce/schema/User.FirstName';
    import EMAIL from '@salesforce/schema/User.Email';
    import communityBasePath from '@salesforce/community/basePath';
    import {NavigationMixin} from "lightning/navigation";
    
    
    export default class UniversalIntakeForm extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
        @track error;
        @track email; 
        @api recordId = ID;
        email = EMAIL;
        firstName = FIRST_NAME; 
        user; 
    
       
        navigateToInternalPage() {
            // Use the basePath from the Summer '20 module to construct the URL
            this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                type: 'comm__namedPage',
                attributes: {
                    pageName: 'testPage__c'
                }
            });
          }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer the documentation [PageReference Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_page_reference_type)

```
navigateToInternalPage() {
    // Use the basePath from the Summer '20 module to construct the URL
    this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
        type: 'comm__namedPage',
        attributes: {
            name: 'Custom_Page'
      }
    });
}
```

> **name**: The unique name of the Experience Builder page. The value for name is the API Name value for a
> supported page. The API Name field can only be defined when a new
> page is being created, and must be unique. If the API Name isn’t
> defined upon page creation, it’s automatically generated.

Comment: Just needed a second set of eyes. Didn't see the typo.